# Drupal 6: How to create a special case for searches on a limited set of single symbols (such as @ and ! and " and : )?

Tags: 6, search

For the system I'm creating pages for some symbols have special functions. I have pages/nodes with those symbols as their title. @ and ! especially at issue because they appear in two different contexts (entirely different meaning in each), so there's two pages for each of them '@ (context A)' and '@ (context B)'.

When a user uses the Drupal Search, and searches solely on '@', those nodes should be in the search results. So far, I'm getting 'You must include at least one positive keyword with 0 characters or more.' when searching on the symbols, even after reducing the required word length to zero (I forced cron to run after doing so).

Does Drupal 6 strip out all or some of the symbols from the search text?

After playing with this for a while it occurred to me that since there's very few of these the approach might be to simply create a special case for them in the search. Is there a hook I could intercept in a module to handle the special cases? What's the best approach here? :)

Added Information:

To clarify, 'context A' and 'context B' were merely made up examples. the real thing would look more like: '@ (primitive)' and '@ (prefix)'. A search on '@' should turn up both, since the site has no way of knowing which (prefix or primitive) the user needs to know about.

Comment: Hi, maybe I didn't understand your question, so I have to ask. So, I created two nodes with the exact title "`@ (context A)`" and "`@ (context B)`" for a simple test (http://i.imgur.com/8PTNW.png). After that, I tried to do a regular node search, here are the results: http://i.imgur.com/sZjBA.png, so Drupal finds both of them, containing an at (@) sign. I also tried the same after renaming one of the nodes: http://i.imgur.com/3c4iD.png. Does your question mean that the same stuff doesn't work on your site?

Comment: Okay that's strange. I'll go back and try again and try disabling various modules to see if there's a module I've installed that is getting in the way.

Comment: Oh. After some fiddling, I realized a difference between what we're doing. You searched on '@ (context' . I'm searching on '@' by itself. Currently, I'm getting this error "You must include at least one positive keyword with 0 characters or more."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a fresh look at the problem this morning, I took a stab at finding out how to create a module to solve it. I think the search terms are run through 'check_plain', stripping it down to just text (no symbols).

Turns out that a module providing the [hook_search_prepocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_search_preprocess/6) hook can override the text used by the indexer and the search. So I put together a module in which my hook does a replacement of '@' with 'atsign', which appears to solve the issue. Also means I can set the minimum word size back to '3', as long as my replacement text is 3 or more characters.

I now have a sites/all/modules/searchfix/searchfix.module file (and corresponding .info file), with the following function in it:

```
function searchfix_search_preprocess($text) {
    return str_replace("@", "atsign", $text);
}
```

Comment: @MPD I was thinking so, but I wasn't sure. I decided to wait a bit in case someone else had a better solution or refinements. 'course, I can always change the accepted answer if someone offers a better one.